# Looping Through two or more intance vars in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view I have two instance variables (going to be more) that I want to display in one table. The first, @data, is an instance var of a model, someting like @data=RnFile.all.
The second is an array @result containing a value per data in @data calculated in the controller. Now in my view I want to display them next to each other, something like:

```
@data[0].atributes @result[0]
@data[1].atributes @result[1]
@data[2].atributes @result[2]
@data[3].atributes @result[3]
...
```

but I can't figure out how to iterate over both the arrays (and propably more to come). 
Any suggestions anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) to do what you want:

```
@data.zip(@results).each do |data, result|
  # use data and result as you need here
end
```